# Navigation Bar buttons not appearing

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add buttons to my navigation bar through code, but they are not appearing for me.  I think it might have to do with my navigation bar being inside a UIView.

My code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

 UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Interface builder:

[image: Interface builder]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add a navigation bar directly in your view hierarchy. Rather, add a navigation controller, have your view controller as the root controller of the navigation controller, and set the navigation controller as the initial controller of the storyboard (or as the destination controller of segues, etc.).

Comment: I am kind of new to ios programming so this might not make a difference, but I have a tab bar controller and I only want the navigation bar on one of the views. Will that change your recommendation?

Comment: No, it won't. Each tab has it's own controller stack, so one tab can have a navigation controller as the controller (and your controller as the root of that navigation controller), while other tabs can have controllers directly.